# How can I determine the size of the icon is added to the snackbar

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I want to display icons in Snackbar. I add the icon to the snackbar, but I can't change the icon size.
How can I determine the size of the icon is added to the snackbar?

My code;

```
public void altbildirim(Activity context,String yazi,int sure) {        
        View parentLayout = context.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, yazi, sure);
        View snackbarLayout = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView)snackbarLayout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.erroricon, 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
        snackbar.show();
}
```

snackbar image I get is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to set size of the icon, but you can resize the drawable itself before attaching. Here's my code:

```
fun Drawable.resize(width: Int, height: Int): Drawable {
val b = (this as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
val bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false)
return BitmapDrawable(bitmapResized)}
```

And then use it like:

```
val resized = applicationContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.award_icon)!!.resize(150, 150)
tv.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(resized,null, null, null)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of providing the hard coded padding it would be better if we get it from value .

Hope this work :

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.icon_padding));
```